# What does it mean "The reshape function returns its argument with a modified shape, whereas the ndarray.resize method modifies the array itself"?

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy, the reshape function returns its argument with a modified shape, whereas the ndarray.resize method modifies the array itself. But what does this really mean? What's the real difference?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(18)
b = a.reshape(3,6)
a.resize(3,6)

a[0] = -2
print(a)

[[-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]

print(b)

[[-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]

b[0]= -1
print(b)

[[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]

print(a)

[[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

From the code above, resize() and reshape() perform the same operation, on the same data. Why need two of them?

Comment: After cross-checking the Help Center, I'm pretty sure this question meets a baseline level of quality (in particular asking for a 'why', with an answer eliciting a 'what for'). Here in the comments, in an area plainly visible to the asker (who appears to be a newcomer): what is missing/wrong with the question that renders it deserving of downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [15]: a = np.arange(18) 
    ...: b = a.reshape(3,6)
```

I like to examine the properties of arrays with:

```
In [16]: a.__array_interface__                                                                               
Out[16]: 
{'data': (65611776, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (18,),
 'version': 3}
In [17]: b.__array_interface__                                                                               
Out[17]: 
{'data': (65611776, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 6),
 'version': 3}
```

Note that `data` is the same for both.  `b` is a `view` of `a`.  It is a new array object, but it shares the underlying data buffer.  Its shape is different, but changes to `a` will appear as changes in `b` (and visa versa).

Review documentation regarding `view` versus `copy`.  This is an important distinction in `numpy`, so you need to understand it well.

Sometimes `reshape` has to return a copy, as when `order` gets changed.  It's also important to realize the `reshape` cannot change the number of elements.

There's a `reshape` function as well, which in most cases the same as the method.

The `shape` attribute can be changed directly as well:

```
In [19]: a.shape = (6,3)                                                                                     
In [20]: a                                                                                                   
Out[20]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17]])
In [21]: b                                                                                                   
Out[21]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]])
```

That action is in-place, modifying `a` itself.  It's a little more restrictive than `reshape`, and not used as often.  For example we could have made `b` with one line:

```
b = np.arange(18).reshape(3,6)
```

The key difference in `resize` is that it can change the number of elements.  It can truncate, or it can increase the size.  The `resize` method and function both do this, but have different 'padding' rules.  And the `resize` method operates in-place.

In your example, `a.resize(3,6)` changed `a` in-place, changing its `shape`, but did not change its data buffer, or `b`'s link to that buffer.  So changes to `a` also appeared as changes in `b`.

My `a` after the in-place `shape` change still has the same `data`:

```
In [22]: a.__array_interface__                                                                               
Out[22]: 
{'data': (65611776, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (6, 3),
 'version': 3}
```

and the same `data` after a `resize` method.

```
In [23]: a.resize(3,6)                                                                                       
In [24]: a.__array_interface__                                                                               
Out[24]: 
{'data': (65611776, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i8')],
 'typestr': '<i8',
 'shape': (3, 6),
 'version': 3}
```

Note that if I try to `resize` `a` in a way that changes the total number of elements, I get an error.  That's because `b` shares the data buffer, and we can't change the size of `a` without affecting the size of `b`.

```
In [28]: a.resize(4,6)                                                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-f7d47a627631> in <module>
----> 1 a.resize(4,6)

ValueError: cannot resize an array that references or is referenced
by another array in this way.
Use the np.resize function or refcheck=False
```

I think you'll find `np.reshape` and `a.reshape` are used quite a bit. `resize` in either form is not used nearly as often.  `reshape` is more predictable and safer.  `resize` can do the same, but it also lets you do dangerous stuff.

I'd focus on understanding the difference between a `view` and `copy`, and secondarily the difference between making a new array and doing in-place changes.

Comment: Good insight on the underlying data buffer! Computer memory is always in linear fashion, it looks like resize and reshape are just virtual "Views" of the same linear memory. 

The only differences seem to be:
1) resize can change the physical memory size, if only if there is no references to it. (What's the point?,  Who cares,then )
2) resize is "in-place", eg. a.resize(), while reshape returns a reference, e.g. b=a.reshape(). So, a.resize() is equivalent to a=a.reshape(). Neither creates a new copy of the original array.

In summary, not much differences btw the two in practical sense.

Answer (score 0):

It means that one function will modify the array, and you only will have the modified array.

The other will return a new array, modified, but leave the original one untouched. It will use double the memory, but the original array will remain available for other calculations.

Depending on the circumstances you might prefer the one or the other.

Comment: The answer seems not to be correct. Neither function will return a new array. Modification will all impact the original array. e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best explained through examples.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(18)

b = a

print(a)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
print(b)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]

print("Reshape - doesnt change the base array")
print(a.reshape(3,6))
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
# [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
print(b)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]

b = a.reshape(3,6)
print(a)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
print(b)
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
# [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15 16 17]]

a = np.arange(18)
b = a

print(a)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]
print(b)
# [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17]

print("resize changes the actual base array")
a.resize(3,6)
print(a)
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
# [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
print(b)
#[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
# [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
# [12 13 14 15 16 17]]
```

Comment: resize() does not return a reference, but operates on self. basically a.resize(3,4) ==  a=a.reshape(3,4). The real difference between the two seems: one does not return a reference, the other returns a reference.